# Difference between array_walk() and array_walk_recursive() in php?

Tags: php, arrays

What is the difference between `array_walk()` and `array_walk_recursive()` in php? Please provide with examples.

Comment: have you looked at the manual or done any research?

Comment: I find it odd that this question has been voted down 4 times yet is the #1 Google result when searching the question. If SO is supposed to be the go-to resource for quick answers to common questions without having to sift through primary sources (e.g. documentation, manuals, etc.) then why the negative reaction to a question I myself just had and found here?

Answer (score 1):

We can use array_walk_recursive() for multi-dimensional    array.

```
array_walk() // Its useful for one-dimensional array.

array_walk_recursive() // Calling array_walk() function in recursively (i.e., function call inside the same function).
```

Answer (score 0):

More then enough explanation and examples

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php